# Prefetching multimedia files in react

Tags: reactjs, web, frontend, assets

I wanted to prefetch all the audio files first before initializing the react app. The files  is very huge about 450mb and whenever i deploy the app on server the audio play with a delay of 2-3 sec. How can i overcome this situation?